# How to solve linear ODE? $e^{x^2}$ messing it up.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve the ODE

$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2xy = x^2$?
It's a linear equation with $P(x)=2x$ but that mean the integrating factor $e^{\int P(x) dx} = e^{x^2}$ which is really bad because then you integrate $\int x^2e^{x^2}$ which I'm not sure is possible to integrate?

By the way, I know there is some way to integrate $e^{x^2}$ involving spherical coordinates. I can't find any examples but if someone has a link to an explanation can they share it?

Given the context the question appeared in it is unlikely we were expected to integrate difficult functions (the focus was on ODEs) but maybe there was a typo in the question :(

Comment: There isn't a way to do this without invoking a special function. You get the error function from it.

Comment: I agree,you'll need to use some kind of numerical method or a Taylor expansion. You won't be able to solve it in closed form no matter how you solve it.

Comment: Note that there *is* an elementary solution if you put $x$ on the right side instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $u=x,dv=xe^{x^2} dx$, you get $du=dx$ and $v=e^{x^2}/2$. So parts gives

$$\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2} x e^{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \int e^{x^2} dx.$$

The latter term is a form of the error function, so you're correct that there is no elementary solution. The polar coordinates trick you are referring to only works when integrating over the entire line; it does not furnish a general antiderivative.

That said, a valid, if non-elementary, solution is

$$e^{x^2} y(x) - e^0 y(0) = \int_0^x y^2 e^{y^2} dy = \frac{1}{2} x e^{x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^x e^{y^2} dy.$$

Equivalently:

$$y(x) = e^{-x^2} y(0) + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2} \int_0^x e^{y^2} dy.$$

Comment: Yes,but you can use polar coordinates to solve the last term as a double integral with a dummy variable. The result is $\frac{sqrt (Pi)}{2}$.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Only on the entire line. For this ODE you need an actual antiderivative.

Comment: Got it,it doesn't work over this indefinite domain.